# Does implicit typecasting in C maintain the same rank for char and short variables?

Tags: c, char, short, typecasting-operator

In C programming the implicit typecasting order from Higher to lower:

[image]

is the rank of char and short same here, means there is no implicit conversion from char to short or short to char right?

char is - 1 byte,
short is - 2 bytes

since the size is different for both these types, how they would be in the same rank?

Comment: Where did that image come from?

Comment: Searched randomly in google

Comment: That is a bad image, not representative of the actual ranks or conversion procedures specified in the C standard. `char` has lesser rank than `short`, `short` has lesser rank than `int`, and so on, and only the integer types have ranks. `float`, `double`, and `long double` do not have ranks. Conversions are specified in rules called the *integer promotions*, which do not involve floating-point types, and in the *usual arithmetic conversions*, which involve floating-point types but have somewhat complicated rules going beyond rank. Do not use that image.

Comment: The Internet is known to contain incorrect information...

Comment: Also note there is no “implicit typecasting”. A *cast* is an explicit operator in source code. C does have implicit conversions, not implicit casts. There are implicit conversions in multiple places, and different rules apply to them in different places.

Comment: Anyway have a look at [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules). It addresses conversion rank.

Comment: The diagram seems to be missing `long long` and doesn't mention `intmax_t` or the types like `int64_t` and `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Aren't those fixed-width types mapped to the other ones anyway? If not by standard, then de-facto at least?

Comment: @saipraveen Note, too, yet another problematic issue: `float` has larger overall value range, but with 32-bit long less precision than signed or unsigned `long`; i.e. you cannot represent all values within [LONG_MIN;LONG_MAX] as a float *exactly* (you are potentially losing some least significant bits) – and same again for 64-bit `long long` and `double`...

Answer (score 4):

The image you have provided is wrong.  First, it's flat-out incorrect to rank `short int` with `char` types.  Per [**6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**, paragraph 1 of the (draft) C11 standard](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1):

> The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.

And C numeric types have a much more complex arrangement than the simple linear "rank" of the image.

Note that the floating point types `float`, `double`, and `long double` are not ranked with the integer types in 6.3.1.1 quoted above.  As noted in the comments on your question, when numeric types are mixed they are subject to what are called [usual arithmetic conversions](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8):

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause
> conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to
> determine a common real type for the operands and result. For the
> specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
> domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real
> type. Unless explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also
> the corresponding real type of the result, whose type domain is the
> type domain of the operands if they are the same, and complex
> otherwise. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions:
>
> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is long double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>   to a type whose corresponding real type is long double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is double, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>   to a type whose corresponding real type is double.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain,
>   to a type whose corresponding real type is float.62)
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
>   - Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>     integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with
>     greater rank.
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand,
>     then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of
>     the operand with unsigned integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with
>     unsigned integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is
>     converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer
>     type.

Note the order there - first, types are converted to an appropriate floating point type, if applicable.

Then "Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands."  That's important - variables of a type smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`) before calculations are performed.  The image you provided does not address that.  [Integer promotion is specified as](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the integer promotions.

Only after all that are the integer ranks applicable.

And all of that is done on a per-operator basis, by precedence.  Some results might be surprising if you weren't aware of that:

```
int a, b;
float x;

...

float y = x + a/b;
```

In that case, the calculation of `a/b` is done using integer arithmetic, not floating-point.  Only *after* `a/b` is calculated as an integer value is it converted to a `float` and added to `x`.  So if `a` is less than `b`, `0.0` will be added to `x`.